# The smooth action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R} \times F$ where $F$ is a manifold

Tags: manifolds, group-actions, quotient-spaces, diffeomorphism, foliations

**Introduction to Foliations and Lie Groupoids**, Book by **Ieke Moerdijk** and **Janez Mrčun**, Chapter **1**, Page **16**.

The smooth action of $\mathbb{Z}$, defined on $\mathbb{R} \times F$ by $$(k,(t,x)) \mapsto (t+k, f^k(x))$$ or $$(k,(t,x)) \mapsto (t-k, f^k(x))$$

The first choice in the one that is mentioned in the book but I think the second choice is the right one.

[image]

Comment: In what sense is one action 'the right one'?

Comment: I mean there might be a mistake in the book it should be $t-k$ instead of $t+k$.

Comment: I think its just a choice. The first action has quotient the mapping torus of $f$, while the second action has quotient the mapping torus of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese the final result is the same?

Comment: The two quotient manifolds are diffeomorphic. The map $\varphi: \mathbb{R}\times F \to \mathbb{R}\times F$ given by $(t, x) \mapsto (-t, x)$ is equivariant (with one action on the domain and the other on the target). It descends to a diffeomorphism between the mapping torus of $f$ and the mapping torus of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments, these two group actions are equivalent. That is, if $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ denote the two group actions, there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}\times F \to \mathbb{R}\times F$, $(t, x) \mapsto (-t, x)$ such that the following diagram commutes

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}\times F @>{\varphi}>> \mathbb{R}\times F\\
@V{\Psi_1}VV @VV{\Psi_2}V \\
\mathbb{R}\times F @>{\varphi}>> \mathbb{R}\times F.
\end{CD}$$

Said another way, the two group actions are conjugate via $\varphi$; i.e. $\Psi_2 = \varphi\circ\Psi_1\circ\varphi^{-1}$. It follows that $\varphi$ descends to a diffeomorphism of the quotients. In the first case, the quotient is the mapping torus of $f$, and in the second case, the quotient is the mapping torus of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, Merci, Danke